# Virtualenvwrapper not working due to too many python versions installed

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am following [this guide](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/) to be able to use OpenCv.

On the step where it says to source the script (**`source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`**), I get the following error message:

```
/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python: Error while finding module specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

If I run **`whereis python`** I get `/usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3.5-config [...]`

Which I feel is the source of the problem because doing `python -V`
gives me     `Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)`
instead of  `Python 2.7.12`, which I've been told should be the Ubuntu default installation, and which is what I get if I remove anaconda from PATH.

So what I feel is happening is that anaconda is forcing (maybe it all is my fault and I configured it this way and do not remember) to be the default python execution, and to be 3.6, and when I try to install this package it can not run since it expects something else.

Is there any way to clean this mess up? Because the problem is that I do not know HOW it is supposed to be to work so I can not fix it, at the moment.

Comment: What is the result of running `pip freeze | grep virtualenvwrapper` in your terminal?

Comment: I now have two terminals. In the one I forced anaconda to be the last variable of PATH, I get: virtualenvwrapper==4.8.2. In the one it is as it was from the instalation, it freezes and returns nothing.

Comment: In the later terminal, what version of Python is installed?

Comment: 3.6, more specifically: $python -V returns: 
Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)

Comment: Try `pip3 install virtualenvwrapper`

Comment: For both that option and other I saw looking around I get "Requirement already satisfied: virtualenvwrapper in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"

Answer (score 0):

Change your path variable -Point To python 2.7

Comment: My path variable right now looks like /home/user/anaconda3/bin:/home/user/bin:/home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

So, no python in sight. How should I do this? Thanks regardless

Comment: See what does echo $PYTHONPATH returns and then try this if it's not empty.  PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/my_python_distribution
export PYTHON

Comment: It is empty. This is going beyond my knowledge haha, thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solution will help anyone else in the future, but since it is my own question, here is what is **apparentely** working for me. And I say that because all this problem comes from installing openCV and I am not done nor I have any more experience than when I started.

In bashrc: `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/home/youruser/anaconda3/bin/python3.6`
 to `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2.7`

Once that is done, I am able to do `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`
 even though any new terminal opened keeps showing the error message